# Which is the best StackExchange site for Debian related questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

Where on Stack Exchange should Debian specific questions be raised?

Two possibilities are here on Unix & Linux, and on Server Fault.

I'm guessing there isn't an equivalent of AskUbuntu for other Linux flavours?

Comment: Note that unless you are a professional system administrator, your Debian questions will not be on topic on [sf]. This is by far the best place for them anyway.

Comment: @terdon - is that really the case? Surely questions from an amateur server admin running a hobby server are legitimate to ask there!?

Comment: I believe Super User would also apply.

Comment: @JeremyDavis They have no way to check, who are you. The question has to be looking like coming from a professional. It is the theory. In practice, their this rule didn't result an elevated quality of the posts, but it resulted a lot of disappointed users.

Comment: @peterh - Thanks. FWIW, I'm sure that here is probably a better place for Debian server questions anyway, I was just being a bit of a wanker making a point... :)

Comment: @JeremyDavis it is true in that that is their scope. They only deal with professional systems; setting up your laptop is off topic there. They also expect a certain minimum level of knowledge. It is not a site for people who are learning *nix.

Comment: A Debian SE would be great!

Answer (score 25):

If we only consider *Stack Exchange*, the best venue for Debian questions is [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

There aren’t many distribution-specific Stack Exchange sites; I’m only aware of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: maybe also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Jeff that covers all operating systems for the Pi, including [Windows](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) ;-).

Answer (score 10):

If you want to ask outside Stack Exchange there are [many other places](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianResources).

Answer (score 7):

In my experience [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is good for anything that is from the perspective of using Ubuntu as a GUI based desktop.

If my question relates to command line or is something general across linux distros I will use [the Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Be aware that even though Ubuntu is Debian based, it doesn't mean that questions regarding Debian will be considered [on-topic at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)